# Is there a known locking or performance degradation in boost:regex 1.54?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Our software is relatively regular expression intensive.
Some months ago we moved from boost::regex 1.33.1 to boost::regex 1.54. Lately we noticed scalability degradation.

What it means is that when we run stress test with 1 or 2 threads there's no much difference between the releases. But when the number of threads is 4 or more we start to see a serious worsening in the operation times, up to 30% worse in 1.54 (compared to 1.33).

This is multi-platform service so we tried it on Solaris and used plockstat. We got this output (I crossed out with `---` some of our exact class names):

`863 428886322 lib---.so 'boost::detail::spinlock_pool<1>::pool_+0x2b8 lib---.so' bool boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<const char*,---_Allocator<boost::sub_match<const char*> >,boost::regex_traits<char,boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::find_imp()+0x110`

So our current assumption is that there's a locking issue in boost or that "::find_impl" in 1.54 has degraded its performance compared to earlier version.

**So the question is** did you encounter such a problem with regex 1.54? (and not less important - did you find a solution?)

Just before you mention it - we know there's a newer boost::xpressive. We currently prefer to check our options with regex 1.54 before we go that path.

Comment: I use boost 1.54, Have you included the regex source in your project or are you using the libs?

Comment: Check to see if `BOOST_HAS_THREADS` is defined.

Comment: Have you played around with the defines listed in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/regex/user.hpp

Comment: Always use separate `match_reusults` (typedef'd to smatch) for each thread.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. 
We're compiling the sources locally and use the generated libs in shared objects. We have BOOST_HAS_THREADS defined. 
Regarding the other two questions - I still need to check, but at the least we theoretically checked and we think we're good with the various defines.